# JavaScript not work in PHP Files ( Box Shadow While Scrolling )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My problem :

1. JavaScript is not working at my .php files
2. My CSS not work while scrolling

*CSS Files named "var.css"

```
#kepala {
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    background - color: #EBEBEB;
    height: 35px;
#kepala.scrl {
    box - shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

---

*PHP Files named "home.php"

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

if($_SESSION['user'] == "blabla"){
?>

<html>

    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='var.css'>
    </head>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        $(function(){
            $(window).on('scroll', function(){
                if ( ! $(document).scrollTop()) {
                    $('#kepala').removeClass('scrl');
                } else {
                    $('#kepala').addClass('scrl');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <body>
        <div id="kepala">
            Blablabla
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I just can't understand why my JavaScript doesn't work. 
There is no effect when I'm scrolling down the header.

Comment: You did not include jQuery

Comment: Hummm,Hummm......nice catch @Spokey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using jQuery, but you haven't included it. Add the following line in the head before your script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```